# FreePBX/Asterisk Recorded Calls not moving to correct location

Tags: asterisk, freepbx

FreePBX: 10.13.66-12/ISO install

Asterisk: 13.12.2

asterisk-addons: Latest

Users reported not being able to see/download on demand recordings from the UCP. The calls are however being recorded, /var/spool/asterisk/monitor is full of files, files that should have been moved to the appropriate date directories.
e.g. 2016/12/15.
I have setup a Post Call Recording Script that is set in FreePBX, this also doesn't run. It is simply to see if it ever gets called, appends to a file.

`-rw-rw-r--   1 asterisk asterisk    120364 Dec 15 17:20 1481858418.2722.wav`

`-rw-r--r--   1 asterisk asterisk    147884 Dec 16 10:02 1481918523.4964.wav`

The top file permissions were changed after running `fwconsole chown`. This leads me to think that asterisk doesn't have the correct permissions.

This is the breakdown of the debug log for MixMonitor

```
[2016-12-15 17:03:14] VERBOSE[20476] app_mixmonitor.c: Begin MixMonitor Recording SIP/200-00000125

[2016-12-15 17:03:24] VERBOSE[20476] app_mixmonitor.c: MixMonitor close filestream (mixed)`

[2016-12-15 17:03:24] VERBOSE[20476] app_mixmonitor.c: End MixMonitor Recording SIP/200-00000125

[2016-12-15 17:03:24] VERBOSE[20476] app_mixmonitor.c: Copying recordings for Mixmonitor SIP/200-00000125 to voicemail recipients

[2016-12-15 17:03:24] WARNING[20476] format_wav.c: Unable to set write file size
```

I have tried changing permissions, re-installing the asterisk-addons, and many other things. Any ideas out there?

Answer (score 0):

Answering my own question.

This is an issue with digium phones and freepbx. Digium uses their own technique to record and save calls. https://wiki.asterisk.org/wiki/display/DIGIUM/Phone+Features+by+Environment

There is a solution to have the calls show up in the CDR and User Portal, but involves changes to the system. **Use at you own risk**.

Create an executable script belonging to the asterisk user, I keep mine in the asterisk user home directory.

```
#!/bin/bash

#this script is run from an incrontab

MONITOR=/var/spool/asterisk/monitor/
if [ -d "$MONITOR$1" ]; then
    exit
fi
if [ ! -f "$MONITOR$1" ]; then
    echo "$(date): Failed to move a recording. \"$MONITOR$1\" does not exist." >> /var/log/asterisk/moved_recording_log
    exit
fi

filename=$1
uid=${filename%.*}

if [ $(sed -e "s/^.wav//I" <<< "${filename##*.}") != "wav" ]; then
    exit
fi

CONF=/etc/asterisk/res_odbc_additional.conf
user=$(awk -F"=>" '/username=>/ {print $2}' ${CONF})
password=$(awk -F"=>" '/password=>/ {print $2}' ${CONF})

db=$( mysql asteriskcdrdb -u $user -p$password -se  "SELECT cnum, calldate as date FROM cdr WHERE uniqueid = \"$uid\";" 2>/dev/null )

ext=$(echo $db | awk '{print $1}')
read -r -a dbd <<< "$db"
IFS="-" read -r -a dbdate <<< "${dbd[1]}"

if [ -z "${dbdate[0]}" ] || [ -z "${dbdate[1]}" ] || [ -z "${dbdate[2]}" ]; then
    exit
fi

dir="/var/spool/asterisk/monitor/${dbdate[0]}/${dbdate[1]}/${dbdate[2]}/"
mkdir -p $dir

name="ondemand-${dbd[0]}-${dbd[0]}-${dbdate[0]}${dbdate[1]}${dbdate[2]}-${dbd[2]//:}-$filename"
db=$(mysql asteriskcdrdb -u $user -p$password -se  "UPDATE cdr SET recordingfile=\"$name\" WHERE uniqueid = \"$uid\";")
mv $MONITOR$filename $dir$name

exit
```

The next step is what watches the recordings directory for any files that have been written.

As the asterisk user edit incrontab

```
incrontab -e
```

add the following with the location and name of the above script

```
/var/spool/asterisk/monitor/ IN_CLOSE_WRITE /bin/bash /home/asterisk/move_recordings.sh $#
```

This is based on a pretty generic FreePBX setup. There may be a nicer way to do this, but this has been working for me.

Answer (score -1):

Correct solution - write file in place where it should be, i.e it to 2016/12/15

It is impossible guess what you dooing wrong(no scripts provided, config etc), but i can suggest you have selinux or permission issue.

Comment: This is my crash course into freepbx and asterisk. As far as what i know the system was setup vanilla, i can supply any configs, i just dont know what ones.

Comment: just checked selinux and its disabled. At end of day i might try bringing the freepbx version up to current

Comment: Debug is OffTopic on SO. You have read book/listen courses and try yourself.